# unable to create desire string in c#

Tags: c#

I have following code

```
while (i<(count-1))
{                    
   string temp = null;       
   if (i == 0)
   {
        temp = "\"" + arry[i] + "\"";
   }
   else
   {
        temp = "," + "\""+arry[i]+"\"";
   }
   demo = demo + temp;
   i++;
}
```

this is giving string demo

demo = `"\"0\",\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\""`

but i want in format demo=`"0","1","2","3","4"`

Comment: @BenAaronson He was escaping the " so he can add it to his string

Comment: string `\"0\"` is considered same as `"0"`

Answer (score 7):

The IDE will display the escape characters (\") but when the string is used they won't be there

Try writing it to the console and checking if it's correct

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to use code like this:

```
var demo = string.Join(
    ",", 
    Enumerable.Range(1, count)
        .Select(n => string.Format("\"{0}\"", n)));
```

Breaking it down a bit...

```
Enumerable.Range(1, count) //Gives a list of integers from 1 to count

.Select(n => string.Format("\"{0}"\"", n) //Surrounds each integer with double quotes

string.Join(...) //Joins the strings above using the comma
```

Answer (score 0):

string template = "\"{0}\"";

```
        while (i < (count - 1))
        {
            string temp = null;
            if (i == 0)
            {
                temp = string.Format(template, arry[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                temp = "," + string.Format(template, arry[i]);
            }
            demo = demo + temp;
            i++;
        }
```